# How to use string::replace with a char*

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, std

I am trying to replace a substring with char*, the strng::replace refuses to take anything that is not a const string *

```
   map<string,char *> renamed_files;
   map<string,char *>::iterator rename_it;
```

Is there any way of using cPath to replace the substring in the map?

```
   rename_it = renamed_files.begin();
   char cPath[1024];
   string strpath = cPath;
   rename_it->first.replace(0,len, strpath);
```

Comment: you mean const char * .. right ? Why not use const_cast to convert char * to const char * ?

Comment: Are you really trying to change the *key*?

Comment: even so, I am trying to do a string replace, it is not compiling at all, it gives me the error saying string::replace doesn't recognize any of 11 types of overload.

Comment: Also, in the above code `strpath` is initialized with garbage because `cPath` is garbage.  This can't be your intent.

Comment: @JohnDibling: You are right about me trying to change the key. That is some abysmal coding. But, cPath is modified elsewhere during the program, but I have not mentioned it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the key in a map is const. Therefore the problem is that `rename_it->first` is const but `replace` is (of course) a non-const member function.

If you were to somehow modify it, that would change the correct position of the entry in the map, but the map has no way to detect that you're changing the string, so it can't move the entry. To avoid the whole problem, modification is forbidden.

You can remove the entry and add a new one with a different key but the same value. Be careful about the validity of your iterator as you do so.